# Combining AND and OR in Catch2 test tags

Tags: catch2, catch-unit-test

I have a set of Catch2 test cases, segregated by language and by type.   For example:

```
TEST_CASE("zh-CN CPU test", "[zh-CN][cpu]")
{
    REQUIRE(result);
}

TEST_CASE("zh-CN verification test", "[zh-CN][ModelVerification]")
{
    REQUIRE(result);
}

TEST_CASE("zh-HK CPU test", "[zh-HK][cpu]")
{
    REQUIRE(result);
}

TEST_CASE("zh-HK verification test", "[zh-HK][ModelVerification]")
{
    REQUIRE(result);
}

TEST_CASE("zh-TW CPU test", "[zh-TW][cpu]")
{
    REQUIRE(result);
}

TEST_CASE("zh-TW verification test", "[zh-TW][ModelVerification]")
{
    REQUIRE(result);
}
```

What I'd like to make happen is to run *just* the zh-HK and zh-TW ModelVerification tests.

But from my reading of the docs, this doesn't seem to be possible.

If I say `[zh-HK],[zh-TW] [ModelVerification]`, Catch2 will run all the zh-HK tests, all the zh-TW tests, and all the ModelVerification tests.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/test-cases-and-sections.md#tags) (updated since your question) it is possible.

In stead of the `(zh-HK OR zh-TW) AND ModelVerification` logic you could use a `(zh-HK AND ModelVerification) OR (zh-TW AND ModelVerification)`. In your case it would be:

```
[zh-HK][ModelVerification], [zh-TW][ModelVerification]
```

P.S. Take care of the spaces and the commas. Catch is sensitive to those.